# Creating UITabBarItem from an array

Tags: swift

I'm writing an app that needs to create a number of tabs based on values from a database. It gets given a list of Pupils and Class numbers from a CSV file, and imports them into a database.  I can run a SELECT DISTINCT on the database and I get a list of class numbers (eg -2, -1, R, 1, 2) and I can iterate through the list fine using

```
for class in classnumbers {

print (class[0])

}
```

and see a list of my class numbers, but I'm banging my head against a brick wall trying to generate the tabs at runtime.  I've got the code:

```
    let firstVc = UIViewController()
    firstVc.title = "First"
    firstVc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "Home", image: UIImage(named: "HomeTab"), tag: 0)

    tabBarCont.viewControllers = [firstVc]
```

This will create a tab when it loads like I expect, so I know that works, and I can add secondVC etc to create more...  What I'm struggling with is using my class number instead of firstVC - so I'd like to be able to generate them like this:

```
for class in classnumbers {

        let class[0]Vc = UIViewController()
            class[0]Vc.title = "class[0]"
            class[0]Vc.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "class[0]", image: UIImage(named: "class[0]"), tag: 0) 
        tabBarCont.viewControllers = [class[0]Vc]

}
```

and so on for each class in the database. I've seen the question answered with "use an array", but I can't see how that would be any different to looping round my database results, and I've seen "you can't do that with swift" - so is it do-able or do I need to come up with a different way of looking at the problem?  (I won't know the class numbers / names that a school use until after getting their data - if I have to hard code them, I'd have to recompile the app for every different school?)

Comment: Check out this tutorial and see if it helps https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/programmatically-creating-uitabbarcontroller-in-swift-e957cd35cfc4

Comment: I looked at that page earlier, and whilst he is creating the tabs programmatically rather than through Storyboard, he inputs all the names manually - I need to do it from a list rather than hand coding them in.

Comment: Is class your own variable? Or is this some swift magic I've never heard of using class keyword?

Comment: No - it’s a variable name - and looking at it fresh, maybe registrationGroup would have been a better one... but then I’d still need to create the regGroup[0]Vc etc

Comment: I'm confused what you're accessing with `class[0]`?  Your first for-loop at the top you're using a for-each loop and access the `class` index 0?  What is this value?

Comment: @Dom it’s a set of rows fetched from a database - the rows are accessed via the classNumbers variable, so class[0] gives you the value of the first column. In this situation, they are school class numbers (1,2,3...) but different schools may use different numbering or even names, hence my desire to use the value of one variable to create another.